# How to use regex to get a certain number of characters before a string? (Python)

Tags: python, regex, text-mining

I am trying to pull years of experience from Indeed job descriptions. Almost all of the descriptions list experience like this: "0-2 years" or "2+ years" or "2 years". Regardless of how it is listed, the word "years" comes after the number of years of experience required.

How could I return a certain number of characters (in this case max 4 including the space) before the word "years" to capture the digits?

I plan on then extracting the digits if it is in string form and averaging them to return one value to be used in a machine learning model. I am removing any job descriptions which require double digit experience values (ex. 10) so this will not be an issue.

So for example:

Example Description: "Ideal candidate will have 0-2 years of experience with Apache Spark."

Desired Output:

Either "0-2" as a string so I can extract the digits manually, or even better a list of digits [0,2]

Answer (score 1):

For your three types of use cases, and one counterexample this would work:

```
In [54]: l
Out[54]: ['0-2 years', '2+ years', '2 years', '5 areas']

In [53]: for s in l:
    ...:     print(re.findall(r'(\d+)[+]?(?=(\-\d+\syear|\syear))',s))
    ...:
['0', '2']
['2']
['2']
[]
```

You have to put the `+` and `-` in either a character class `[]`, or escape with `\`.

There's a positive lookahead `?=` for either 1) a hyphen, digit(s), a space, and "year"; or 2) a space and "year".

Answer (score 0):

I think this regex achieves what you're looking for:

```
import re

s = "Ideal candidate will have 0-2 years of experience with Apache Spark."
matches = re.findall("([^\s]+) years", s)
print(matches)
```

Result:

```
['0-2']
```

Comment: it's also matching `some years` which then causes problems in the averaging part